# custom timer job is running multiple times in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, visual-studio, custom-timer-job

I have created a Web application scoped timer job in SharePoint 2013. This timer job is supposed to be running only once in a month , and should send an email only once . The problem i am facing is this job is running multiple times ,we have 2 WFE servers and it is running from both one by one. I checked several blogs and everyone says to put

`(SPJobLockType.job)` in the constructor :

```
  public TimerJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webapp)
  : base(jobName, webapp, null, SPJobLockType.Job)

  {

            this.Title = "My Timer Job";

  }
```

which i have already done . the code is as below:

```
    class TimerJob : SPJobDefinition
    {
        public TimerJob()
            : base()
        {
        }

        public TimerJob(string jobName, SPService service)
            : base(jobName, service, null, SPJobLockType.Job)
        {
            this.Title = "My Timer Job";
        }

        public TimerJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webapp)
            : base(jobName, webapp, null, SPJobLockType.Job)
        {
            this.Title = "My Timer Job";
        }

        public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
        {
            UpcomingNotifications.Run();  
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me something guys that this timer job should not run more than once.

Comment: Do you want the timer job to be executed only once in lifetime? Timer jobs basically runs on the give schedule. Hourly/Daily/Weekly/Monthly/Yearly like this. Please be specific what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have missed to set the timer job schedule for your time like below

```
CustomTimerJob job = new CustomTimerJob(JobName, site);
SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
schedule.EndSecond = 59;
schedule.Interval = 15;
job.Schedule = schedule;
job.Update();
```

Job Schedules:

[Minute Schedule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spminuteschedule.aspx)

[Daily Schedule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spdailyschedule.aspx)

[Monthly Schedule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spmonthlyschedule.aspx)

To know more about SharePoint timer jobs, [Click here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S)

Comment: i have done that , but when we set the time from central admin it runs only on that time ,doesnt it .

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple Server Environment. Please follow these links.[Stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953585/best-practices-for-deploying-timer-jobs-in-server-farm-environments-with-multipl), [Martin Hatch Blog](https://www.martinhatch.com/2009/08/sharepoint-timer-jobs-and-multiple.html)

If the above links helps, kindly mark this as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

actually I found out what I was doing wrong. When I was deploying this solution, I was deploying it on the central admin and the web application on which it should run,but for some reason it was getting deployed on all other web applications as well. I went to `central admin->monitoring->Job definitions` , and disabled the timer job from other web apps and only kept it enabled on the one I wanted it to run and it started working as I wanted i.e only once.

Hope it helps someone having the same issue .